# Building Per User Customizable Systems

Tags: web-applications, architecture, relational-database

I am building a web application where I want to build a form that is per-user configurable. For example, the user should be able to specify "I want a select box with a list of values I give you for input A, a textbox for input B, and another select box with a list of values I give you for input C". Then, the user can later fill out the form based on how they customized it. To be clear, this is not a system to build html forms for your own webpage. The form lives and integrates with the rest of the application.

I have a couple of ideas in my head on how to implement this, but I am curious how others who have built similar applications have dealt with similar problems (i.e. per-user customizable systems). I don't care about a specific language or framework, although you can point to some if it helps explain your solution.

A) creating a fairly complex relational database schema (needs a User table, a User_Fields table, a Fields_SelectValues table, and then for record keeping a SubmittedRecord table that includes the fields with their actual values on a submit. Actually, there will need to be another table SubmittedRecord_FieldValues that maps the user specific field values to a given SubmittedRecord). The results of a submit will then be used throughout another part of the application, so lookups on submitted values will be done a lot. This is the most robust, but likely the slowest to use (good # of joins to get all of the date you may need) and hardest to implement. Also, this could be overkill since most users will have a significant overlap in the way they want things setup.

B) Instead of building all of the data needed to build everything like above, I store an HTML blob for each user. Then I can have a field in a SubmittedRecord table called "Values" that is just a delimited string of their field names and submitted values. This makes for quick lookups, but slow to select on an individual field later. But mostly, I am concerned that this anti-relational schema has some unforseen issues that I haven't yet thought about.

How have you seen this kind of thing done before?

Note: I am not necessarily looking for a solution to my exact problem, just general advice on this type of problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option B sounds like a security risk and a maintenance nightmare.

Option A sounds much better.

Depending on your platform / framework there should already be mechanisms built-in which help with user profile related capabilities; so I'd see what currently exists in your chosen platform first.

I know that ASP.NET has a couple of mechanisms that provide solutions in this space.

A big consideration(which will impact design and implementation of such a system) will be how to build the "schema" of the profile in the first place; is it "baked-in" to the system or can admins dynamically (through the UI) modify the schema?